# Dynamically updating an ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This should be easy for any one who knows Angular--I, on the other hand, am super new to it. I was trying to put together an easy example using `ng-include` but it's not clear why the variable inside the include is not updating.

I include some html in the page (not sure if ng-model is necessary):

`<div ng-model="template" ng-include="template.url"></div>`

I have a button:

`<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-model="template" ng-click="switch()" ng-href="#">Change!</a>`

that calls a function from the controller which looks like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.templates =
        [ { name: 'Template1', url: 'views/template1.html'},
        { name: 'Template2', url: 'views/template2.html'} ];

    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.switch = function() {
        $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
        console.log($scope.template);
        return $scope.template;
    };
}
```

);

The variable that shows up in the console? Correct. But nothing changes on the page.

UPDATE: So this code works. What's required is the removal of the href attribute, which in some cases was reloading the page. If that's true, then is there a way to do this in which there is a failsafe? i.e. the href works fine without javascript, but the ng-include works when javascript is working?

Comment: do you know ng-route and ng-view? It's looking like this what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I do not know those. I'll go look them up.

Comment: What you're doing here seems fine, its almost identical to the example given in the documentation for ng-include. You don't need the ng-model's however, since you're not using any input/select tags. Nor does your switch() function need to return a value... but I can't see how either of those things would prevent it from working.

Comment: The documentation for hg-include has an example very similar to this but with a dropdown menu. My problem is I don't see where in the code the dropdown menu is activating anything. I'd really like to know why what I have doesn't work.

Comment: [works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/lsnusIfYrVNK5lSpLL0p?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks okay, [try it in this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/XW6C2Boq5nOw0WM1vtTE).  The only thing I changed was the URL to the templates.

---

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/6wHL5/) also showing that it works with and without ng-href.
`<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="switch()" ng-href="#">Change!</a>`
`<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="switch()">Change!</a>`
After seeing Sunil's comment, I added in bootstrap css to make it clear that href is not needed to get the desired styling.  It can be removed without any problems.  But, unfortunately, plnkr and jsfiddle are not reproducing the reload you experienced.

Comment: What! The code was correct? It turns out that the button (with all the styling) appeared to be reloading the page. Removing ng-href="#" allowed it to work properly now—I think that counts for points to you!

Comment: @ruzel that's nice... note you should use ng-href only with angular expressions. In this case you just want href="#" ... without an href the browser won't show a hand cursor when you mouse over the `<a>` tag. PS: you should also mark this as the accepted answer to give him more points :)

Comment: Actually @SunilD. you can get the browser to show the right cursor by using CSS. Since my link is `<a class="btn">` I can use the css `a.btn { cursor: pointer; }` to make sure that any element shows the interactive cursor.

Comment: Also @SunilD. I didn't right-away realize that there might be a difference between href and ng-href. So does plain-old href get overridden by AngularJS? i.e. the way one might override an href with Jquery and `e.preventDefault()`?